# How can I search a file for a character in position 12 and if found delete that and next 5 characters from all lines?

Tags: sed, cut

I am trying to parse an RSS feed and condense down the info on the line so that I still have the date and time of the entry, but without milliseonds or wasted spaces because I am feeding the file to the xscreensaver text crawl that is limited on readable screen width.  I could change my code to not add the 2 heading lines until after the text is formatted if that would be much easier.  Thanks for any ideas...

```
The input file at this point looks like this:

ABC World News Feed
RSS Data retrieved from https:--abcnews.go.com-abcnews-headlines
05-24 18:48:16    Truckers' strike leads to fuel shortages in Brazil
05-24 18:48:16    The marathon atop the world's deepest lake
           ^^^^^^
           Remove these character positions starting from 12 to 17 
           from each title line, with colon in 12 but not from the heading lines

So the result should look like:

ABC World News Feed
RSS Data retrieved from https:--abcnews.go.com-abcnews-headlines
05-24 18:48 Truckers' strike leads to fuel shortages in Brazil
05-24 18:48 The marathon atop the world's deepest lake
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take would be to replace a colon followed by two digits followed by at least one space with a single space:

```
$ sed 's/:[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]  */ /' file
ABC World News Feed
RSS Data retrieved from https:--abcnews.go.com-abcnews-headlines
05-24 18:48 Truckers' strike leads to fuel shortages in Brazil
05-24 18:48 The marathon atop the world's deepest lake
```

If you want to be really specific about the position, you can anchor the search with `^` to the start of the line and use parentheses with backreference `\1`. Here the dot `.` matches an arbitrary character:

```
$ sed 's/^\(..-.. ..:..\):[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]  */\1 /' file
ABC World News Feed
RSS Data retrieved from https:--abcnews.go.com-abcnews-headlines
05-24 18:48 Truckers' strike leads to fuel shortages in Brazil
05-24 18:48 The marathon atop the world's deepest lake
```

Comment: I used the 2nd version of this and it worked perfectly.  I need to read and play more, as I don't understand "backreference".  I will go look that up, thanks.  PS: sorry, not allowed to upvote.

Comment: @BobC A backreference like `\1` represents the part that the first pair of parentheses matched. You can also use `\2`, `\3` and so on for the second, third, ... pair. You can *accept* the answer that helped you most by clicking the check symbol to the left, giving you another 2 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '$2 ~ /[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/{sub(/:[0-9]+ +/,OFS)} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` too in above command.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation here too.

```
awk '
$2 ~ /[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/{ ##Checking condition here if 2nd field is matching digit colon digit colon digit pattern then do following.
  sub(/:[0-9]+ +/,OFS)       ##Using substitute function of awk to substitute colon digit(s) then space with OFS whose default value is space in current line.
}
1                            ##awk works on method of condition and then action, so making condition TRUE here and not mentioning action so print will happen.
' Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Suggestion to aid viewers: avoid long lines to avoid horizontal scroll bar. They are a pain to read.

Comment: This code did also work.  You can select all and paste into Geany I found, and the comments become more readable.

Comment: @BobC, cool, glad that it helped you, you could up-vote those answers which helped you to encourage people, cheers and happy learning !!